# Android - Padding not changing with state in layer-list

Tags: android, xml, button, selector, padding

I am trying to create button states where the normal state is a light color with a dark band on the bottom, and the pressed state is a dark color with a light band on the top. All of this is working fine. However, I want the padding to change with the state as well, and this is not working fine. (Note that the padding is equal to the height of the bands, and the selector has “variablePadding” enabled). The padding remains in the normal state. Has anyone encountered this, or know of any solutions? Thanks!

Normal State:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="20dp"
                android:top="0dp"/>
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="80dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/green_light"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"/>
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="20dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/green_dark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Pressed State:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:top="20dp"/>
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="20dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/green_dark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"/>
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="80dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/green_light"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:constantSize="true"
          android:variablePadding="true">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer my question, but I realized I should be able to achieve the desired result with a 9-Patch

Comment: However, even setting the content, the padding doesn't seem to change between states...